# Expo in Bare RN project: Firebase AdMob and Analytics conflict about GoogleAppMeasurement

Tags: xcode, firebase, react-native, expo, cocoapods

Tried to install two packages in Bare React Native:

- [expo-ads-admob](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/admob/)
- [FirebaseAnalytics](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/firebase-analytics/)

It works fine on Android but problems occurs on iOS with "pod install"

Looks packages have conflict in theirs dependencies:

- EXAdsAdMob - GoogleAppMeasurement (~> 7.0)
- EXFirebaseCore - GoogleAppMeasurement (= 8.13.0)

```
  In Podfile:
    EXAdsAdMob (from `../node_modules/expo-ads-admob/ios`) was resolved to 12.0.1, which depends on
      Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK (= 7.69.0) was resolved to 7.69.0, which depends on
        GoogleAppMeasurement (~> 7.0)

    EXFirebaseCore (from `../node_modules/expo-firebase-core/ios`) was resolved to 4.1.1, which depends on
      Firebase/Core (= 8.13.0) was resolved to 8.13.0, which depends on
        FirebaseAnalytics (~> 8.13.0) was resolved to 8.13.0, which depends on
          FirebaseAnalytics/AdIdSupport (= 8.13.0) was resolved to 8.13.0, which depends on
            GoogleAppMeasurement (= 8.13.0)
```

All solutions that I found had failed. E.g. I tired update project with below code but still got the error.

```
target 'project' do
  pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK', '8.13'
end
```

Also `pod repo update` or `pod install --repo-update` didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a problem with EXAdsMob. At least version [8.5.0](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/Specs/5/9/a/Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK/8.5.0/Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK.podspec.json#L5) of Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK is required for compatibility with Firebase 8.x.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can I do anything to fix it? Or just stop using one of those packages?